# Microsoft Graph batch limit on v1.0 is less that 20 and not always the same

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using batching in the v1.0 endpoint and it's not working to combine 20 requests as stated.
Most of the times 15 requests are working, sometimes only 14.

The error I get for the requests that exceed the above numbers is 429 (ErrorTooManyObjectsOpened).

I have added an example of such a batch request which contains 15 times "DELETE /me/events/{id}". One request failed while the other 14 worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a server side issue. Somehow you opened too many concurrent sessions to the server. They will eventually timeout. The best experience is never to get too close to the threshold. If you have a lot of request to handle, batch it several times.

Comment: I have tested it first thing in the morning, the application sent a batch request with 15 elements and one failed with a 429. And this happens regularly. The application sends a request with 15 elements and after that a second request with less. The first request often has one element with an error (429). Sending a request with more than 15 elements is never working.

Comment: So the batch requests may be queued in the Server side, the actual threshold is 15. But we cannot sure why the 1st request with 429.